# Spring boot issue in loading the server.context path when application deployed in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I am facing issue with spring boot.When I run spring boot as standalone application it is considering the server.context-path.
But when i deploy same application in tomcat container(not the default in spring boot) it is not considering the server.context-path and loads the application in root context.

**http://localhost:8080/book-service/**(deployed on tomcat)

```
{
   "_links" : {
"users" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/book-service/users{?page,size,sort}",
  "templated" : true
},
"profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/book-service/profile"
}
 }
}
```

**http://localhost:9001/v1.0/**(running as spring boot application it is considering the context path(v1.0)

```
{
"_links" : {
"users" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:9001/v1.0/users{?page,size,sort}",
  "templated" : true
},
"profile" : {
  "href" : "http://localhost:9001/v1.0/profile"
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is no issue, work as designed. The `server.*` properties only apply when you are running standalone NOT when deployed into a container.

Comment: Is there any way to do that

Comment: Configure your tomcat accordingly.

Comment: Is there any configuration component in spring boot to do that..Like the way we used to do in web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below property

```
                      spring.data.rest.basePath=/v1.0
```